# Angular with Firebase - best practice to reduce amount of reads/writes

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

So what I got is a simple CRUD Application and a firebase.service in my App which handles the firestore connection.

In this service there is this function

```
read_Students() {
  return this.firestore.collection('Students').snapshotChanges();
}
```

I have multiple pages which subscribe to this changes like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.crudService.read_Students().subscribe
...
```

I was wondering if this code structure consumes a lot of reads and writes if I subscribe to snapshot changes at every single page (one per page per change) and if so: is there a better way to have just one instance that listen to changes and just subscribe to that one instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the collection has many children this could add up quickly for sure.
and if this collection is shown in many places, you will be better of with storing it in a state. This will prevent any unnecessary reads and improve latency because your state is local and synced with the firestore/realtime-database.